# display other fields of a entity reference field

Tags: drupal-7

Let's say I have a content type of "person", which contains details about that person. I have another content type of type "house", and I want to use an entity reference field to select different people, but when the content type is displayed I want not just the person's name (the title of the referenced node) but all the other details. I have tried selecting the View mode "Rendered entity", with view mode "full content", which I would expect to display all the fields - but I can't get it to work - it just displays the title.

Answer (score 1):

Have you set up the full content display to display all fields?
Go into your person content type - go to custom display down in options.
Then up in the top right corner you should have default, teaser, and full content links. 
Go into full content and make sure all fields are being displayed.

Comment: Thank you! I actually went through the whole process of setting it up again and the second time it worked. Now I have the problem of the Title of the person being displayed as a link and "Read more" being displayed at the bottom...

Comment: they should be sortable in your view. the read more is part of the pager section - switch the items to display field. Fot the title of the person if you click on format or fields there should be a check box "link this field to original content" - uncheck that

Comment: By creating a view and using the entity selection mode "views" rather than "simple", I have it displaying exactly how I want it on the editing page (The persons full details with a little tick box next to it). However, the _display_ doesn't allow me to select the view method of display. Any idea how to do that?

Comment: sorry. havent used that myself.